# Sybase expert help: groupby aggregate performance problems

Tags: performance, group-by, sybase, case-when

Hey I have the following tables and SQL:

T1:  ID, col2,col3  -  PK(ID)   - 23mil rows

T2:  ID, col2,col3  -  PK(ID)   - 23mil rows

T3:  ID, name,value  - PK(ID,name)  -66mil rows

1) The below sql returns back the 10k row resultset very fast, no problems.

```
select top 10000 T1.col2, T2.col2, T3.name, T4.value 
from T1, T2, T3  
where T1.ID = T2.ID and T1.ID *= T3.ID and T3.name in ('ABC','XYZ') 
and T2.col1 = 'SOMEVALUE'
```

2)  The below sql took FOREVER.

```
select top 10000 T1.col2, T2.col2, 

ABC  = min(case when T3.name='ABC ' then T3.value end)  
XYZ  = min(case when T3.name='XYZ ' then T3.value end)  

from T1, T2, T3  

where T1.ID = T2.ID and T1.ID *= T3.ID and T3.name in ('ABC','XYZ')
and T2.col1 = 'SOMEVALUE'

group by T1.col2, T2.col2,
```

The only difference in the showplan between those 2 queries are the below for query 2).  I dont understand it 100%, is it selecting the ENTIRE resultset WITHOUT top 10000 into the temp table then doing a group by on it? is that why it's slow?

```
STEP 1
    The type of query is SELECT (into Worktable1).
    GROUP BY
    Evaluate Grouped MINIMUM AGGREGATE.

    FROM TABLE ...etc..

    TO TABLE
        Worktable1.

STEP 2
    The type of query is SELECT.

    FROM TABLE
        Worktable1.
    Nested iteration.
    Table Scan.
    Forward scan.
    Positioning at start of table.
    Using I/O Size 16 Kbytes for data pages.
    With MRU Buffer Replacement Strategy for data pages.
```

---

My question is

1) Why is query 2) so slow

2) How do I fix while keeping the query logic the same and preferably limit it to just 1 select SQL as before.

thank you

Answer (score 1):

Although possibly a generic answer, I'd say to put a index on the columns you're grouping by.

**Edit / Revise:** Here's my theory after re-looking at the issue.  The SELECT statement in a query is always the last line executed.  This makes sense as it is the statement that retrieves the values you want from the dataset specified below.  In your query, the whole dataset (millions of records) will be evaluated for the MIN value expression that you specified.  There will be two seperate functions called on the entire dataset, since you have specified two MIN columns in the select statement.  **After** the dataset is filtered and the MIN columns have been determined, the top 10000 rows will then be selected.

In a nutshell, you're doing two mathematical function on millions of records.  This will take a significant amount of time, especially with no indexes.

The solution for you would be to use a derived table.  I haven't compiled the code below, but it's something close to what you would use.  It will only take the min values of the 10,000 records rather than the whole dataset.

I.e.

```
    Select my_derived_table.t1col2, my_derived_table.t2col2,
    ABC  = min(case when my_derived_table.t3name ='ABC ' then my_derived_table.t3value end),  
    XYZ  = min(case when my_derived_table.t3name='XYZ ' then my_derived_table.t3value end)
    FROM
      (Select top 10000 T1.col2 as t1col2, 
              T2.col2 as t2col2, 
              t3.name as t3name, 
              t3.value as t3.value
       from T1, T2, T3
       where T1.ID = T2.ID 
         and T1.ID *= T3.ID 
         and T3.name in ('ABC','XYZ')
         and T2.col1 = 'SOMEVALUE') my_derived_table
group by my_derived_table.t1col2, my_derived_table.t2col2
```

Comment: I cant, it's all dynamically generated, we have over 200 tables, each with 50+ columns. User can select any table, any column they want, and those are the columns we use group by on. I like to understand more why this group by is causing performance problems. What it is doing internally that's the bottleneck. Thanks